# How do EOS tokens appear at bloks.io?

Tags: tokens

At bloks.io there are tokens with USD estimation. How is it calculated?

How do these tokens appear on that page?

Who / What evaluates them?

Comment: Since bloks.io is a private closed source service, you should ask their creators, links are on their website. [EOS Cafe Block](https://eoscafeblock.com/) and [HKEOS](https://www.hkeos.com/). They have an incentive to be friendly and will probably answer all your questions. They have a vested interest in their project. You can also ask them to answer here for others to see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bloks.io uses this github repo and asks anyone who wants to have their token listed on their site to submit a PR. https://github.com/eoscafe/eos-airdrops
Ignore that they named it eos-airdrops, it is for all tokens (including non-airdropped).

Answer (score 0):

Bloks.io used to use our API which uses multiple sources such as Chaince and Newdex.io to create a single source of EOS token data. They migrated to newdex.io.

Our API is freely available at:
https://blocksense.one/api/token.json

Also, I think Bloks.io does not "evaluate" the EOS token projects before listing them on their site. They are a block producer and provide this listing service as part of their community efforts.

Also, if you are interested in finding a list of EOS token projects, check out:

https://github.com/BlockABC/eos-tokens

I hope this helps.